# DateTime range parameter with two where conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Select * from order as o
where (@datefrom is null or @dateto is null  
              or o.orderdate between @datefrom and @dateto)      
       or (@datefrom = o.orderdate)
```

I want to use the `datefrom` and `dateto` parameters for a date range selection OR I can type date like `01.06.2014` in the `datefrom` parameter, in which case `dateto` will be `null`.

This means I want to use the `datefrom` parameter for two filters but when I type a specific date in the `datefrom` parameter and `dateto is null` the data is not correct according to typed date.

Please help with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when `@datefrom` is `null`, then the entire `where` clause evaluates to `True` for every row - so the `where` clause isn't doing anything.

Here is one way of achieving what you want:

```
IF @dateto IS NULL SET @dateto = @datefrom;

Select * from order as o
where o.orderdate >= @datefrom
  and o.orderdate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dateto);
```

Note that I haven't used `between` because it can be really ambiguous and confusing with dates - see [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for why.

Answer (score 0):

So to be clear. If both `@datefrom` and `@dateto` are entered then you do a range check. If only `@datefrom` is entered, you do an equality check. If so, this should work:

```
select
    *
from
    order o
where (
    @dateto is not null and
    o.orderdate between @datefrom and @dateto
) or (
    @dateto is null and
    o.orderdate = @datefrom
)
```

I note in your example you're also testing @fromdate for null. Does that mean anything in particular?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for a query like this would be dynamic sql something like this ......

```
DECLARE @datefrom DATETIME = '20140101' 
DECLARE @dateto   DATETIME = '20140303'

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql  = N' Select * from [order] '
          + N' WHERE 1 = 1 '
          + CASE WHEN @datefrom IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN N' AND orderdate >=  @datefrom ' ELSE N' ' END
          + CASE WHEN @dateto IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN N' AND orderdate <=  @dateto   ' ELSE N' ' END 


EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@datefrom DATETIME , @dateto DATETIME'
                     ,@datefrom
                     ,@dateto
```